# ¿cómo envío el resultado de una consulta echa con php, por email?

Tags: php, mysql, email, wamp

estoy haciendo una consulta con php a mysql, y la consulta funciona bien, lo que quiero hacer es el resultado de la consulta lo pueda yo mandar por email, el codigo de la consulta es el siguiente:

```
 $sentencia = $pdo->prepare(" SELECT * FROM detalleventa,vancas WHERE 
 detalleventa.idproducto=vancas.id AND detalleventa.idventa=:ID");
 $sentencia->bindParam(":ID", $claveVenta);
 $sentencia->execute();
 $listaProductos = $sentencia->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

y el código que tengo para enviar el correo es este:

```
 $destino="correo@gmail.com";
 $nombre="dario";
 $correo="hola";
 $telefono="1234567890";
 $asunto="sin asunto";
 $mensaje="";
 $contenido="Nombre: ".$nombre. "\nCorreo: " .$correo. "\nTelefono: " 
 .$telefono."\nMensaje: " .$mensaje;
 mail($destino,$asunto,$contenido);
```

el arreglo que me retorna es este:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 5 [idventa] => 59 [idproducto] => 5 
[preciounitario] => 10515 [cantidad] => 1 [vendido] => 0 [modelo] => RE-1063 
[vista1] => RE-1063 [vista2] => [vista3] => [nombre] => Banca Italiana 3 
Plazas [descripcion] => Banca Italiana de 3 plazas tapizada en tela de 
importación con retardan de flama y protector de manchas blockaide. [color] 
=> Basting, Bobbin, Seam, Shears, Thimble, Thread, Admiral, Charcoal, Honey, 
Platinium, Sand, Scarlet, Slate,Acero, Azul, Granada, Naranja, Oxford, 
Verde, Artico, Cactus, Ocean, Onix, Trebol, Vid, Volcano, Arak, Armeida, 
Carmania, Lori, Pashto, Cabernet, Cinder, Intensity, Olivo, Pinery [precio] 
=> 4967 [Descripcin_Tecnica] => Banca de polipropileno 4 plazas, estructura 
acero tubular redondo de 2" cal.-16 de 4 patas cromadas y travesaño de 2", 
asiento y respaldo inyectados en polipropileno de alta resistencia con 
diseño ergonómico para máximo soporte lumbar, lo que permite estar sentado 
largo tiempo sin sentir incomodidad, colores asiento y respaldo negro o gris 
[Uso] => Visita / Espera [Dimensiones] => Altura Piso-Asiento: 44 cm. Altura 
Fondo: 61 cm. Altura Frente: 163 – 219 cm. Altura Total: 83 cm. [Garantia] 
=> 2 años [Marca] => Requiez ) )
```

y este arreglo que puede variar de objetos es el que quiero mandar por correo como cuerpo del mensaje, gracias a todos, espero me ayuden.

Comment: Hola buenas noche, una pregunta lo que tu desea es mandar el arreglo como lo estas mostrando lo  los valores de este.

Comment: no tan literal asi como esta. pero si quiero enviar los valores de cada posición, por ejemplo este arreglo solo tiene una posición, pero en esa posición almacena varios datos como se muestra arriba y quiero obtener todos los valores de cada posición del arreglo. Ejemplo: id=1, idventa=2, precio unitario=1000, cantidad=1...   id=i, idventa=3, precio unitario=2000, cantidad=4... y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: Hola @DarioQuiroz, ¿aún necesitas ayuda con esta cuestión? ¿Qué error aparece? ¿Qué has intentado hacer?